# Neo4j Node Linking

Tags: java, neo4j

Hello I am trying to create a simple neo4j DB.  I have a for loop that creates a new node for every file in a directory

```
for(file f : files){
        Node document = graphDb.createNode();
        document.setProperty( "name", f.toString().trim());
        graphDb.getReferenceNode().createRelationshipTo(document, MatrixRelationshipTypes.REFRENCE);
```

that works fine.  Then I am trying to create a node for each name found in a file:

```
                Node pName = graphDb.createNode();
                pName.setProperty("name", name.toString());
                pName.createRelationshipTo(document, MatrixRelationshipTypes.CONTAINS_NAME);
```

The problem is it creates a Node for every name found, which I understand is what my code is telling it to do.  What I really want is for it to create a node IF one of that name doesn not already exisist.  And if one of the name does exist link it to both documents it exist in.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html). There are also [auto-indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html) which handle the indexing (at the end of the transaction for you).

```
Index<Node> nameIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("names");

public Node getOrCreateNode(String name) {
  Node found = nameIndex.get("name",name).getSingle();
  if (found!=null) return found;
  Node nameNode = graphDb.createNode();
  nameNode.setProperty("name",name);
  nameIndex.add(nameNode, "name", name);
  return nameNode;
}
```

You can then also query the index for nodes using wildcards (Lucene search syntax).

```
IndexHits<Node> nodes = nameIndex.query("name:Jo*");
```